# Out of memory issues within Matillion

Tags: amazon-web-services, out-of-memory, heap-dump, matillion

Users of Matillion that have experienced out of memory errors. How did you find the root cause for these types of errors and what did you do to prevent them in the future?

We got the heap dumps that where produced due to these errors and looked into the jobs that are hogging the most memory. However when it comes future proofing this from happening and tracking memory intense jobs in real time what is your strategy for this?

Comment: These two documents might be helpful? [Possible causes](https://support.matillion.com/s/article/Error-Out-of-Memory-Error-detected-on) and [Troubleshooting guide](https://support.matillion.com/s/article/What-is-the-process-for-troubleshooting-Out-of-Memory-OOM-errors-in-Matillion-ETL)